# What 'styles' of testing frameworks are out there?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, bdd

It looks to me that testing has come a long way since SUnit, JUnit, and the common xUnit test frameworks.

I looked into [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) and [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) to get an idea what 'behavior-driven' testing is about, but now I do wonder which kind of other approaches to writing unit-tests exist.

I am not tied to any particular language, but more interested in general ideas and approaches to test code.

So, my question is, which stylistically different approaches are there to unit testing, i.e., approaches different from "asserts".

Let me give examples:

The xUnit style of unit-testting looks roughly like this in your favorit language:

```
stack = new Stack()
assertTrue  (stack.empty())

stack.push(1)
assertFalse (stack.empty())
assertEquals(1, stack.top())
```

RSpec-style unit-testting looks rather like this (roughly improvised):

```
describe Stack do

  it "should be empty" do
    Stack.new.empty?.should == true
  end

  it "should contain new value on top" do
    stack = Stack.new
    stack.push(1)
    stack.empty?.should == false
    stack.top().should == 1
  end
end
```

Are there other interesting styles, notations, 'DSLs'?
Sure, every language and framework will have variations on the theme, but are there different general 'themes'/styles?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I entirely understand your question correctly. There are unit testing frameworks as NUnit, the one built-in in Visual Studio and several others. These can be used for state based testing. If you also want to use behaviour based testing you may need to use one of the isolation (mock) frameworks such as Rhino Mocks, MOQ, TypeMock, ... Furthermore you could perform integration testing for testing multiple components together. Automated UI testing is another tool, as well as e.g. soapUI for testing web services (although I would see this as integration testing).

Comment: I tried to expand the question. Hope that it makes it more clear.

Comment: Not sure it fits your question, but I've seen devs putting `// Given`, `// When`, and `// Then` comments in their jUnit tests to help write them by describing a precondition, tested event, and expected result.

Comment: @DamienPollet, yes, that's the kind of things I am looking for. With your keywords, I found an interesting link: http://www.rapaul.com/2009/08/09/bddmockito-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of two styles of tests. Code centric (xUnit and RSpec given the code above) and behavior centric (cucumber, SpecFlow - Given/Then/When). 
Now you can do behavior styled tests in code-centric frameworks (code #1).

You also have three types of tests:

- Mockists - Most of the dependencies are (strictly) mocked.
- Stubbists - Most of the dependencies are stubbed.
- Integration - Most of the dependencies are real.

Code#1:

```
@Test
public void theScenarioDescription() {
    givenThatSomething();
    whenIWiggleIt();
    thenSomethingHasHappened();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I really like the Given, When, Then type syntax for testing.

```
Given some particular situaion
When some action occurs
Then there will be an outcome that can be verified.
```

I started out with this approach using tools like [StoryQ](http://storyq.codeplex.com/) and [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) on .NET, which are really tidy. I've since started writing my own [little framework](https://github.com/gregjsmith/Jerky)  which is more suited to my own personal style, but isn't particularly mature yet.